# Custom 404 php page returning 200 instead of 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have set up a custom 404 page and have the following code within the header:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

Then within my .htaccess file I have the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

However for some reason when testing the site I am told the page is still returning a 200 instead 404 error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is Your htaccess file configured correctly in apache site config ? Does it have proper permissions to run ?

Comment: Thanks Michal, yep it has the same set up as my other websites which is why I don't get why this one isn't working, plus I have other functions running in my .htacess file such as removing file extensions and so on and they are functioning properly, it's just the 404 error ? Weird?!?